# Can't create InstallShield2015 LE setup project after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield-le, license-key

After upgrading to Windows 10 an error occured when opening an existing Visual Studio 2015 solution with a setup and deployment project.
First I got an error that my license key was corrupt.

Then I tried to do the online re-activation as stated in the error message from InstallShield. It didn't help. I could not reactivate my InstallShield 2015 LE for Visual Studio 2015 Professional.
After an email to Flexera they suggest the following steps:

Please try the following steps to repair your license.

1. If InstallShield or Visual Studio is open, please close them.
2. Delete any file(s) with MVSN in the filename at the following location (you will need to enable hidden files and folders): 
   On XP or older: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\FLEXnet
   On Vista or newer: C:\ProgramData\FLEXnet
3. Re-launch InstallShield and activate the software using your product serial number.

...

After these steps I got an empty solution when I try to create a setup and deployment solution.
Then I tried uninstalling InstallShield2015LimitedEdition followed by a re-install. Strange thing is that there was no activation screen where I could provide my license...

But nothing changed. A new setup and deployment solution ends up with an empty solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Removed the whole Flexnet folder and that worked.

Comment: and deinstall first then remove flexnet folder and reinstall